# Makefile FFLAGS description

Tags: c, makefile, fortran, flags

In the my Makefile i have a flag given by

```
  FFLAG= -Dunix -c -fopenmp -03
```

Can someone explain what the Dunix and -03 flags mean?

Comment: You wrote `-03`, is that a type for `-O3`?

Comment: In addition to considering @AlexanderVogt's answer have a look at your compiler documentation.  It's all in there !

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `-Dunix` is used to define a variable `unix` (here: uninitialized) for the pre-processor at compile time. `-O3` enables optimization at level 3. This optimization and the interpretation is compiler dependent.

All compilers I know honor the flags `-D` and `-O`.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Dunix` flag is equivelent to having `#define unix` in the source file.  This will only matter in Fortran if the preprocessor is invoked, which is typically automatically done for files with a capital F extension (e.g. `.F`, `.F90`) or if the compiler is called with an option to preprocess files or if `cpp` or another preprocessor is explicitly called.

The `-Ox` flags where `x` is one of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `s` (and perhaps some others depending on your compiler) signify levels of optimization performed by the compiler.  For details of what optimizer flags are implied by a specific level, consult your compiler documentation.  In general if you want to step through your code in a debugger and have it make sense, `-O0` is used and typically `-O2` is a reasonable default.